# The quota path is either invalid or it doesn't exist

Tags: file-management, windows-server-2008-r2, quota, username

Using File Server Resource Manager in Windows Server 2008 R2, i'm trying to set a quota of 1 GB for each user folder. But it seems it doesn't recognize the %USERNAME% variable. When I fill in:

F:\Personal\%USERNAME%\

And I try creating the quota, i get an error:

"The quota path is either invalid or it doesn't exist"

But the folders with the usernames do exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `%username%` do when you type it into a Command window?